# How to check facebook log in status in iOS7

Tags: xcode, facebook, ios7

From iOS7, user can login to Facebook without having Facebook installed. Is there a way to check in app that if the user has already logged into Facebook in iOS settings or not ? Does this have to go through FB SDK ? Since Facebook login is integrated into the settings, is there a iOS API to check for the status ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Social Framework to accomplish this. The `SLComposeViewController` class provides a class method `+ (BOOL)isAvailableForServiceType:(NSString *)serviceType`. This will return true if the user has an account set up with the serviceType you pass in.

Class reference for 'SLComposeViewController': https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SLComposeViewController/isAvailableForServiceType:
Service Types: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Service_Type_Constants

Here is a little example:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    //Facebook account is available
}
else
{
    //Facebook account is not available
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That totally helped!